# Replicating an SPSS manova in R

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, spss, manova

I'm trying to replicate the top part of the [SPSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPSS) `manova` table 3.17 shown on page 127 in [**this book**](http://docshare02.docshare.tips/files/31719/317194846.pdf) (*just type `148` in the page number slot*) in `R`. I have written the R code below to replicate that SPSS output but my R output doesn't match.

I was wondering if I'm missing something in my R code that causes the outputs not to match (e.g., see R's Philla vs. SPSS' Philla)?

Here is my reproducible R code:

```
tim <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/tim.csv")

m <- manova(cbind(PEVOCAB, RAVIN)~ 0+NS + NA. +SS, data = tim)

summary.manova(m)

          Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
NS         1 0.94909  307.613      2     33 < 2.2e-16 ***
NA.        1 0.65621   31.494      2     33 2.233e-08 ***
SS         1 0.08361    1.505      2     33    0.2368    
Residuals 34
```

The output from SPSS is:

[image]

Comment: Please include the SPSS output you are trying to replicate and describe what doesn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very familiar with SPSS but as far as I see MANOVA in SPSS reports multivariate tests for each predictor separately (just like `manova` in R). So, it does not report multivariate tests of significance for `EFFECT..WITHIN CELLS REGRESSION` (maybe there are additional options). However, you can obtain these results using [canonical correlation in SPSS](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/dae/canonical-correlation-analysis/) and you can do the same in R:

```
library(CCA)
library(CCP)

tim <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/tim.csv")

dep <- tim[, 1:2]
indep <- tim[, 3:5]

cc1 <- cc(dep, indep)
rho <- cc1$cor

n <- dim(dep)[1]
p <- length(dep)
q <- length(indep)

p.asym(rho, n, p, q, tstat = "Pillai")
p.asym(rho, n, p, q, tstat = "Hotelling")
p.asym(rho, n, p, q, tstat = "Wilks")
p.asym(rho, n, p, q, tstat = "Roy")
```

If you check the output, you can see the lines `1 to 2` (except Roy's) give the results in the table you shared:

```
Pillai-Bartlett Trace, using F-approximation:
               stat   approx df1 df2      p.value
1 to 2:  0.57254350 4.412028   6  66 0.0008280031
2 to 2:  0.09883594 1.819547   2  70 0.1696820737

Hotelling-Lawley Trace, using F-approximation:
              stat   approx df1 df2      p.value
1 to 2:  1.0097601 5.217094   6  62 0.0002113469
2 to 2:  0.1096759 1.809652   2  66 0.1717396749 

Wilks' Lambda, using F-approximation (Rao's F):
              stat   approx df1 df2      p.value
1 to 2:  0.4742758 4.821971   6  64 0.0004072374
2 to 2:  0.9011641 1.809652   2  33 0.1795823708

Roy's Largest Root, using F-approximation:
              stat   approx df1 df2     p.value
1 to 1:  0.4737076 9.900927   3  33 8.35749e-05

F statistic for Roy's Greatest Root is an upper bound.
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for making a reproducible example.  That meant it was possible to give you an answer.

I always find manova to be a painful technique, and it's never clear to me what it's actually testing.

You've made a mistake in your manova code (I believe) because you've run a model with no intercept. It should be:

```
m <- manova(cbind(PEVOCAB, RAVIN)~ NS + NA. + SS, data = tim)
summary(m)
```

Which gives:

```
> summary(m)
          Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
NS         1 0.35267   8.7168      2     32 0.0009507 ***
NA.        1 0.30581   7.0486      2     32 0.0029082 ** 
SS         1 0.02385   0.3908      2     32 0.6796696    
Residuals 33
```

In your case, the R output is the multivariate tests for each of the predictors. The SPSS output is the omnibus multivariate tests. It doesn't appear that SPSS is giving you those tests.

I find it much clearer to model this sort of thing use either a multilevel model, or a structural equation model. That way I know that I'm actually testing what I think I'm testing.

To do the multilevel model, you need to make the data long, and then run the model. Code below.

```
library(tidyr)
library(nlme)
library(lavaan)

tim_long <- tim %>%
  dplyr::mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
  cols= c("PEVOCAB", "RAVIN"), names_to = "outcome",
)

re1 <- nlme::lme(
  fixed = value ~ 1 + NS + NA. + SS + outcome + 
    outcome * NS + outcome * NA. + outcome * SS ,
  random = ~ outcome | id,
  weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | outcome),
  data = tim_long, method = "ML")
summary(re1)
re_null <-   nlme::lme(
  fixed = value ~ 1 + outcome ,
  random = ~ outcome | id,
  weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 + 1 | outcome),
  data = tim_long, method = "ML")

summary(re_null)
anova(re1, re_null)
```

There's a lot of output, here's some of it:

This is the equivalent of the SPSS table. Notice that L.Ratio is pretty close to the Approx F squared. That's the same test.

```
> anova(re1, re_null)
        Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
re1         1 13 472.0548 502.0076 -223.0274                        
re_null     2  7 487.6555 503.7840 -236.8278 1 vs 2 27.60075   1e-04
```

Also notice you've got some parameter estimates in re1 that match the parameter estimates in the book.

```
                     Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)       35.44917  5.365161 33  6.607288  0.0000
NS                -0.20564  0.407966 33 -0.504055  0.6176
NA.                1.01272  0.376845 33  2.687373  0.0112
SS                 0.39773  0.470103 33  0.846057  0.4036
```

My preference (but sadly not most people's) is to use a structural equation model.  You can use the data in the format that you have it.

```
path_model <- 
  "PEVOCAB ~ NS + NA. + SS
   RAVIN ~  NS + NA. + SS
   PEVOCAB ~~ PEVOCAB
   RAVIN ~~ RAVIN
   RAVIN ~~ PEVOCAB
"
path_model_null <- 
  "PEVOCAB ~ 0 * NS + 0 * NA. + 0 * SS
   RAVIN ~  0 * NS + 0 * NA. + 0 * SS
   PEVOCAB ~~ PEVOCAB
   RAVIN ~~ RAVIN
   RAVIN ~~ PEVOCAB
"


path_fit <- lavaan::sem(path_model, data = tim)
path_fit_null <- lavaan::sem(path_model_null, data = tim)

summary(path_fit)
summary(path_fit_null)
```

There's a lot to look at.

First you can look at the estimates from summary(path_fit).

```
Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  PEVOCAB ~                                           
    NS               -0.206    0.385   -0.534    0.594
    NA.               1.013    0.356    2.846    0.004
    SS                0.398    0.444    0.896    0.370
```

These match the multilevel estimates.

Second, look at the fit from summary(path_fit_null):

```
Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                27.601
  Degrees of freedom                                 6
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000
```

That's the omnibus multivariate test (again)! And it matches the lme result.

Comment: Habit. You don't need to put the extra 1. It just explicitly specifies that there's an intercept (which is the default anyway).

Comment: There are implicit latent variables, which are the errors. In some older software you needed to write the model to include latent variables. This is no longer the case.

Comment: Page not found.

Comment: No. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65982611/7223434 is a dead link.

Comment: @rnorouzian - not sure I understand what you're asking. Sorry.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, in your answer above when you say *"Notice that `L.Ratio` is pretty close to the `Approx F squared` [in SPSS table OP posted]."*, you mean `sqrt(L.Ratio)` is close to Hottellings `5.21` Approx F squared?